# Freezing site elements until time pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After clicking "Take a break" number of sets should decrement, and clock should start. 
During clock working, clicking on any element of site should be cousing any effect.

Instead, the first click and it works properly, but after first clock pass, i can click decrement sets during the clock work and click another breaks.

I want to do this without asynchronous stuff (project's requirement ;/ )

I tried adding a freezing variable but i have problem how properly place the ifs.
Here is fragment which i struggle with:

```
var freeze = false
$(".start").click(function(){
if(!freeze){
    freeze = true;
    var num = $(this).attr("id");
    var currExcercise = routineSample.excercises[num];
    var res = this;
    var timer = 0;
    var setsTd = "#set"+num;

    if(!currExcercise.allSetsDone)
    {
        timer = currExcercise.breakTime;
        currExcercise.sets--;

        if(currExcercise.sets <= 0 ){
            currExcercise.sets = 0;
            currExcercise.allSetsDone = true;
        } 

        $(setsTd).text(currExcercise.sets);
        if(!currExcercise.breakPassed){       
            setInterval(function(){        
                if(timer>0){
                    timer--;
                    $(res).text(timer);
                }else{
                    if(!freeze)
                        $(res).text("MOVE ON!");
                    currExcercise.timeLeft = timer;
                    freeze = false;
                    //currExcercise.breakPassed = true;                        
                }

            }, 1000);

            freeze = true;

        }
    }else{
        $(res).text("EXCERCISE DONE");
    }
} });
```

Comment: This is unclear. What is a "set" in this context? What do you mean by "freeze site elements"?

Comment: Set is name of variable, field of currExcercise class. 

Freeze site elements means - when clock is on, klicking on anything doesn't cause any action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "freeze" a page use the following CSS:

```
body { pointer-events: none };
```